# Binding Dictionary<string, IEnumerable> to Pivot control

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, dictionary, binding

I'm trying bind a dictonary to a pivot control containing a datatemplate with an itemscontrol. But only one pivot item appears with no content.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, so if someone could help me find an error or an alternative, that would be great :)

This is the XAML markup:

```
<phone:Pivot Name="visitingHoursPivot" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="324">
    <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="{Binding Key}">
                <ItemsControl Name="rfbItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource contentItemsControl}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding DayName}" Style="{StaticResource App_Content_Grid}" TextAlignment="Left" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource App_Content_Grid_Subtle}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</phone:Pivot>
```

And in code behind I just do:

```
public Openingstijden()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    visitingHoursPivot.ItemsSource = HourDataSource.GetAllHours();
}
```

The ItemsSource is a Dictionary that is created something like this:

```
public static IDictionary<String, IEnumerable<HourItem>> GetAllHours()
{
    IDictionary<String, IEnumerable<HourItem>> result = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<HourItem>>();

    foreach (ProfileItem profile in _hourDataSource.Profiles)
    {
        var hoursLinq = _hourDataSource.Hours
                    .Where(hour => hour.Id == profile.Id)
                    .Select(hour => hour);

        result.Add(profile.Title, hoursLinq.AsEnumerable<HourItem>());
    }

    return result;
}
```

And looks like this when debugging:

[image: Dictionary result]

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `ItemSource` property expects an `IEnumerable`, so you need to transform your data to a collection.

The easiest but quite a messy way would be to convert your dictionary to a `IEnumerable<Tuple<string,IEnumerable>>` where the first item is the key and second are the values, or just create a class holding the key and values and use it.

Comment: I even created a ObservableDictonary class implementing everything like IDictionary, ICollection, etc. But still no content was showing up. I'll make a class and try that approach.